# Stopping the Ping process in bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, security, kali-linux

I created a bash script to ping my local network to see which hosts is up and I have a problem in stopping the Ping process by using ctrl+C once it is started
the only way i found to suspend it but even the kill command doesn't work with the PID of the Ping

```
submask=100
for i in ${submask -le 110}
do
    ping -n 2 192.168.1.$submask
    ((submask++))
done
```

Comment: You can use ping -c n IP, where n is number of times to ping

Comment: I use fping in my scripts. It's faster than ping

Comment: @IncrivelMonstroVerde I forgot to put the -c in my code and increment the submask but i edited it in the above code but this is not the answer it kept pinging although I typed ctrl+c

Comment: ok. Ctrl + C exit a ping, but the next ping starts. Use trap like the example below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ctrl + C exit ping, but another ping starts. So you can use trap.

```
#!/bin/bash

exit_()
{
        exit
}

submask=100
while [ $submask -le 110 ]
do
    fping -c 2 192.168.77.$submask
   ((submask++))
   trap exit_ int
done
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to limit the amount of packets sent with `ping` with the option `-c`.

I also corrected the bash syntax, guessing what you intend to do.

Finally, it is faster to run all the `ping` processes in parallel with the operand `&`.

Try:

```
for submask in ${100..110}
do
    echo ping -c 1 192.168.1.$submask &
done
```

Comment: I have previously tried thisbut i forgot to put it in the above code 
but i have edit it and increased the submask each loop
So if you have any answer kindly help me with